# How to obtain geo co-ordinates of a remote user in group video chat?

Tags: django, video, video-streaming, agora.io

I am building a group video chat application in Django with the help of Agora where I want to show the user their geo distance from every other user. To a given user, the UI would look something like this (along with the video of course)

```
User A - (User A's remote video) - 5 miles away from you
User B - (User B's remote video) - 100 miles away from you
User C - (User C's remote video) - 10 miles away from you

User D (local user - you)
```

Now in the video chat, a user can log off & a new user can join the call any time. To compute the geo distance of a remote user with the local user, I need geo-coordinates of both the parties. I can obtain the geo-location of the local user by integrating with some location library. I am confused on how to obtain the geo-coordinates of the remote user?

My django code flow looks something like

```
        renders           links to
views.py ----> video.html -------> agora.js
```

Video.html renders the video chat room. I am using Agora to power the group video chat whose code is defined in agora.js. Any time a new user joins the call, their video is added to the room. I have attached the code for how a remote user is added to the room.

```
// stream references (keep track of active streams) 
var remoteStreams = {}; // remote streams obj struct [id : stream]

// connect remote streams
client.on('stream-added', function (evt) {
  var stream = evt.stream;
  var streamId = stream.getId();
  // Check if the stream is local
  if (streamId != localStreams.screen.id) {
    // Subscribe to the stream.
    client.subscribe(stream, function (err) {
    });
  }
});

client.on('stream-subscribed', function (evt) {
  var remoteStream = evt.stream;
  var remoteId = remoteStream.getId();
  remoteStreams[remoteId] = remoteStream;
  client.setRemoteVideoStreamType(remoteStream, 1); // subscribe to the low stream
  addRemoteStreamMiniView(remoteStream);

function addRemoteStreamMiniView(remoteStream){
  var streamId = remoteStream.getId();
  var html_code = $('<div/>', {'id': streamId + '_container',  'class': 'remote-video-box col-sm-4'}).append(
      $('<div/>', {'id': streamId + '_mute', 'class': 'mute-overlay'}).append(
          $('<i/>', {'class': 'fas fa-microphone-slash'})
      ) // stripped some code here to reduce complexity but essentially, append stream to html
    );
  $('#remote-streams').append(html_code);
```

I don’t receive any information about the remote user other than their user id. I could integrate with a geo location api in the js code & compute the location of the local user. But I am confused how to obtain the coordinates of the remote user & then render it on the UI?

Comment: Once a new user joins a group video chat -
1. Use your said location library to get coordinates
2. Store coordinates in the DB
3. Calculate distance of new user from existing users
  
The problem really comes when the existing user has to be updated with the distance of the new user. In my opinion, you need "push messaging" to get the existing user to update the info they see with the new info from the DB.
1. Send push message with Google Firebase (or other service)
2. Service worker in your browser receives the message
3. Your JS code now calls your backend to get new users's data

Comment: This is not a trivial problem but hopefully the push messaging solves your issue. You could also establish your own websocket connection instead too - check out Django Channels.

Comment: Would it be possible to transmit remote user co-ordinates with the video stream?Or is that part of code uncontrollable?